# PHP - Error ASCII=16 State=0 Unexpected Character in Input

Tags: php, error-handling

I have come across this error for the first time and can't seem to debug it. My code which concerns this error is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();
$accountUsername = $_POST["username"];
$accountEmail = $_POST["email"];
$accountPassword = $_POST["password"];
$accountPasswordConfirm = $_POST["password-confirm"];
$recaptchaResponse = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
$secretRecaptcha = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

// Send Request Of Recaptcha To Google Servers
$verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secretRecaptcha.'&response='.$recaptchaResponse);
$recaptchaValidation = json_decode($verifyResponse, true);

// Validate Recaptcha Response
//if ($recaptchaValidation["success"] == false) {
    //echo "error:You must solve the reCAPTCHA verification";
    //exit();
//}

// Validate Email Address
$accountEmaili = str_replace("@", "", $accountEmail); $accountEmaili = str_replace(".", "", $accountEmaili);
if (filter_var($accountEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && ctype_alnum($accountEmaili)) {
} else {
    echo "error:You must enter a valid email address";
    exit();
}
if (strlen($accountEmail) >= 5 && strlen($accountEmail) <= 400) {
} else {
    echo "error:You must enter a valid email address";
    exit();
}

// Validate Username
if (strlen($accountEmail) >= 8 && $accountEmail <= 14) {
} else {
    echo "error:Your username must be 8-14 characters";
    exit();
}
```

I have tried to change a few things but nothing works and I have no clue what this error code means too. Could anyone help debug this issue with me, many thanks.

> Error: Warning: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=16) state=0 in /home/nodebase/public_html/WebApp/Backend/UserPortal/Register/CreateAccount.php on line 27
>
> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=16) state=0 in /home/nodebase/public_html/WebApp/Backend/UserPortal/Register/CreateAccount.php on line 27

Line 27 = `if (strlen($accountEmail) >= 5 && strlen($accountEmail) <= 400) {`

Comment: There's something funky happening in `>= 5` and for `<= 400` which doesn't show up in comments, but as a box, but you seem to have edited that out and is unknown if that was part of your working code or not. Might be a hidden unicode.

Comment: I didn't understand you, what do you mean to say?

Comment: when you originally posted your code, there was a kind of "box" for a character that to me might be a hidden unicode character, but that doesn't show now. I think the problem's in there. `var_dump()` and you'll probably see something.

Comment: Which one is line 27?

Comment: I have re copied and pasted the code from my editor without changing anything, and line 27 is there now ive edited the post

Comment: I am pretty sure that you have a unicode character in there that is hidden.

Comment: How do i go to find it?

Comment: by doing a `var_dump()` or `print_r()` and using a code editor which shows hexadecimals source.

Comment: `if (strlen($accountEmail) >= 8 && $accountEmail <= 14) {` < copy/paste that from here and then paste it back in your code. Use a code editor if you're not using one to do this also.

Comment: ASCII 16 seems to be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#DLE and as per http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html --- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII - what editor are you using to code this with? or keyboard setup?

Comment: The one the hosting provider gives me. In a webpage

Comment: When I type my code into https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php, I get two highlighted sections on line 27 which both have a '10' highlighted in purple.

Comment: Did you not copy/paste what I asked you earlier? what did it do after? @EMoments

Comment: Thanks man it fixed it there was a hidden character on both operators on that line.

Comment: You're welcome @EMoments Glad to see that we were able to solve this one. That's what I thought from the beginning when I saw those 2 "boxes" in your code.

Comment: @EMoments you can mark the question as solved by accepting the answer below. This is done on a voluntary basis, but it does inform everyone and the system that the matter was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, there are hidden (unicode) characters in your code that is probably caused by your host's editor.

By copying/pasting the following that I mentioned in comments, will solve this for you.

```
if (strlen($accountEmail) >= 8 && $accountEmail <= 14) {
```

FYI: The hidden characters were before the `>` and the `<` operators.

ASCII 16 is what's called a "DATA LINK ESCAPE" character.

Pulled from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character:

> The data link escape character (DLE) was intended to be a signal to the other end of a data link that the following character is a control character such as STX or ETX. For example a packet may be structured in the following way (DLE)   (DLE) .

Pulled from https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/40801/data-link-escape:

> A communications control character that indicates that the following character is not data, but a control code.